# Not able to show individual Marker Information from HashMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have saved am Object to the HashMap called Memories which I want to pull a BitMap and a Title etc and set it to the Markers InfoWindow when I click on it. I have the InfoWindow showing the Image and Titles etc, but when I add another Marker and create another Memories object. Both Markers show the newest data.

```
@Override
public void showMemory(final Memory memory) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Minions have saved your Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(memory.getTitleMem()).position(memory.getLocationMem()));

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            markers.put(marker.getId(), memory);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null);

            ImageView markerImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.markerImage);
            TextView markerTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.markerTitle);
            TextView markerDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.markerDate);

            if(markers != null && markers.size() > 0){
                markerImage.setImageBitmap(markers.get(marker.getId()).getImageMem());
                markerTitle.setText(markers.get(marker.getId()).getTitleMem());
                markerDate.setText(markers.get(marker.getId()).getFormatedDate());
            }



            return view;
        }
    });

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(memory.getLocationMem()));
}
```

This is where I save my Object into the HashMap and show the contents of the Marker. Am I saving and showing the data wrong in the marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at using `final` is not going to give you what you want.

Your `InfoWindow` adapter is called for every outstanding marker. It is something that you configure on the `GoogleMap`, not on the individual `Marker`. That means `getInfoContents()` is called for every outstanding `Marker`, causing you to update every `Marker`'s data with the same `Memory`.

To fix this:

Step #1: Move `markers.put(marker.getId(), memory);` out of `getInfoContents()` and directly into `showMemory()`. Your `addMarker()` call returns the `Marker` that you can use to call `getId()`.

Step #2: Only call `setInfoWindowAdapter()` once for your `GoogleMap`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'll give that a shot there now :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also thanks for teaching me more about it. Much appreciated!